# Assigning text file data to java variable

Tags: java

[image]I'm pretty sure that I'm really close to getting this working. I have a text file that contains the output of batch file. I want to assign the computer name from within the text file to JLabel selectedComputerFromAD. Currently the text file output looks like this:

```
"CN=COUD111235,OU=Workstations,OU=Mis,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET"
```

I need to grab what CN equals so I want is lblSelectedComputer = COUD111235
Here's what I have so far.

```
            ComputerQuery.sendParam();

             String sCurrentLine = null, CN = null;
             try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\anoc5f\\workspace\\ControlPanel\\resultofbatch.txt")))
                {

                    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        if(sCurrentLine.matches(".*CN=([^,]*).*"))
                        {

                            Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(".*CN=([^,]*),");
                            Matcher m = p1.matcher(sCurrentLine);
                            m.find();
                            CN = m.group(1);
                        }

                    }

                    if(CN != null)
                    {
                        //TODO do somethign with CN
                        System.out.println(CN);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("CN not found");
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


            }


    });
```

Currently    selectedComputerFromAD.setText(sCurrentLine); doesn't work. I'm not even totally sure I'm assigning the right variable to it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work currently? Is no text set at all, or is the entire line set as the text?

Comment: Currently with the code above, I'm getting a null pointer exception.  If I put it inside of the while loop then it outputs every computer name that the while loop goes through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    String str = "CN=COUD111235,OU=Workstations,OU=Mis,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
    String regex = "CN=([^,]*),";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    m.find();
    String computerName = m.group(1);
```

Full example referencing your code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String sCurrentLine = null, CN = null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resultofbatch.txt")))
        {

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                if(sCurrentLine.matches(".*CN=([^,]*).*"))
                {

                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*CN=([^,]*),");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(sCurrentLine);
                    m.find();
                    CN = m.group(1);
                }

            }

            if(CN != null)
            {
                //TODO do somethign with CN
                System.out.println(CN);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("CN not found");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: This only grabs the computer name from the hardcoded string and not from the text file.

Comment: I figured you can fill in the blanks. You can edit while loop condition to be while(!m.find()) on each line read.

Comment: I apologize, but I don't totally understand what you mean with the while loop. I'm not the best at Java. Is there any chance you can show me a working example?

Comment: Thank you for providing a demonstration, I really appreciate it, but when I implement the code into my class, I get "CN not found". I tried also to paste it in as a separate class and made sure that the file path for FileReader was correct, but I still get CN not found. If I look in resultofbatch.txt this is there: "CN=COUD111255,OU=Workstations,OU=Mis,OU=Accounts,DC=FLHOSP,DC=NET"
 so I'm not really sure why it's not extracting the computer name?

Comment: post contents of the file

Comment: See screenshot above to see file contents

Comment: Ok. I assumed the quote mark was not literal. The pattern needed to change. Now it works for your example (edited)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the pattern wrong. You're not splitting `sCurrentLine`, but the String `","`.

You'll also need to call `setText()` from inside the event dispatch thread, otherwise you won't see it until there's a full redraw (if you minimize and maximize the frame, it should become visible).

Comment: Actually, you want to assign tokens[0].split("=")[1]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String CN = sCurrentLine.split("CN=",-1)[1].split(",",-1)[0];
```

Comment: I added this line of code, but I'm getting a null pointer exception. If I put it inside of the while loop then it outputs every computer name that the while loop goes through. I updated the code above.